# Titunium Studio Cannot find Android SDK

Tags: android, installation, titanium, appcelerator, dependency-management

I have a problem with Titanium Studio. It doesn't recognize my Android SDK installation.
In the Platform->Android prefs panel, it says "No Android SDK found in the selected location"

When I first ran Titanium, it installed/updated a bunch of it's own and some Node plugins, so it's fulfilled all dependencies.

details:

- OS: Windows 7 (x64)
- Titanium Studio version is 3.3.1 (in %Appdata%\Roaming\Titanium Studio)
- JDK build 1.8.0_31 (%Program Files (x86)%\Java\JDK)
- Android SDK installation (in C:\Android-sdk)

  - Android SDK tools 24.0.2
  - Android SDK Platform Tools 21
  - Android SDK Build Tools
  - Android 4.2.2, API 17 (all children)
  - Android 2.3.3, API 10 (all children)
  - Android 2.2, API 8 (all children)
  - also everything inside the Extras branch

According to [Titanium Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-AndroidSDK%2FTargetAndroidPlatform), I have at least one Android SDK (4.2.2) that falls within the accepted SDK bounds for my Titanium version.

Comment: _"When I first ran Titanium, it installed/updated a bunch of it's own and some Node plugins"_ - it installed Titanium SDK 3.5.0.GA, Titanium CLI 3.4.1, Node.ACS 1.0.21, & Alloy 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what contributed to the solution (note that titanium CLI alwayes detected everything correctly), but here's what I've done meanwhile.

- I had existing %ANDROID_SDK%, %JAVA_HOME% and the SDK's tools and platform-tools locations added to PATH from the beginning.
- I Uninstalled Titanium (Studio & SDK), JDK+JRE, Node and Git.Then reinstalled JDK and Titanium.
- Titanium installed node 10.13 and Git 14.sth to %programfiles(x86)%
- the problem still existed. Cue another series of uninstalls.
- Installed Jdk, Git, node and Titanium one-by-one.
- Interstingly, this time Titanium couldn't locate Git which was installed in C:\git (it was added to PATH). So I symlikned C:\Git into %programfiles(x86)% (also linked C:\nodejs for good measure :) )
- Now, I found the JDK installer only added C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath to PATH which includes just java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe. So I added %programfiles(x86)%\Java\jdk\bin to PATH.
- This time, Titanium Studio worked correctly!

So, perhaps, the problem lies in Titanium Studio needing dependencies in certain locations.

(btw, before this, even though path to git.exe was in PATH, the Studio's console "couldn't find a 'bash' shell." now it does.)

hope this helps others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked those links?

1.[link 1](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121567/could-not-locate-the-android-sdk-at-a-given-path-in-preferences--android-sdk-directory)

2.[link 2](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127541/titanium-cannot-find-android-sdk)

and it's better to have same architecture of java and OS.
you can also type this in command line and check if there is any specific android issue
 `titanium info`

Comment: Thanks. `titanium info` always found everything correctly.<br>However, I've investigated the PATHs and finally solved the problem.